# Starman what are all these little bits

Tags: spacex, falcon-heavy, payload

I keep seeing all these little partials or bits flying all over the place, any idea what they are (circled in green).

[image]

[image]

Here is one moving in front of the earth.

[image]

Comment: I believe what you can see in the second image is the moon?  It was clear in a booster shot as it was rotating.  I guess the others are just stars.

Comment: Some are moving in different directions, perpendicular to each other, sorry I don't have any screen capture software so I cant do multiple shots quickly.

Comment: Short flashes are probably radiation hitting the camera sensors and the small bits are random pieces of material, mostly paint bits and seat dust.

Comment: I thought it was pretty interesting seeing all these little bits moving around, some pretty fantastic images.  At first I thought hey were just stars, or even other stuff in orbit, then I though maybe just radiation hitting the camera or "space" dust.  Probably a combination of that stuff.

Comment: They look like some sort of flakes. Initial guess would be condensation released by heating/moving parts.

Comment: There are several *if not many* answers already here about the sources of the floaters seen around spacecraft after burns have stopped. This question should not be closed for "primarily opinion based" and those that voted that way *should be instructed not to just randomly click reasons willy-nilly!*

Comment: Is [this](https://youtu.be/aBr2kKAHN6M?t=1h54m28s) what you're talking about? I don't know either and wanted to ask it here too. No stars (they move at different speeds), surely not the moon...

Comment: I was asking the same question. Here is a video of them [here](https://www.reddit.com/user/LeatherUnderstanding/comments/7vw5k9/does_anybody_know_what_those_things_in_the/) I don't think they are radiation flashes on the camera sensor, because they apear behind the car windshield.

Comment: When were the images taken?

Comment: @Carlos - thanks for the video, that was exactly what I was meaning!

Comment: @EricDuminil - yes and thanks for the video, one of the comments said this `It's solid oxygen flaking off the LOX tank valve one of hundreds released. Neccessary thing when flying with liquid oxygen oxidizer.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I noticed that as well and was reminded of the "fireflies" scene with John Glenn in the film "The Right Stuff".

They're almost certainly illuminated frost flakes. As the upper stage rotated in and out of the sunlight, the frost flaked off and swirled about in the light.

Sources:

https://www.universetoday.com/82211/the-mystery-of-john-glenns-fireflies-returns/

http://www.chron.com/news/nation-world/article/The-story-behind-astronaut-John-Glenn-s-10783488.php